# Is it possible to get used TLS version information?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm using the following code:

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl_ptr, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 | CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2 );
```

But I have reason to believe it's not actually using TLS 1.2 still. I was hoping to confirm it somehow, but I can't find what allows you to pull this information from the API.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Look at [`CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TLS_SESSION.html)/[`CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.html) for [`curl_easy_getinfo()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html).  You can use that to access the underlying TLS library, and then you can use the library's own SDK to query it for the TLS version that was used.

Comment: It sets the *minimum* version required so it would then also allow 1.3. Why do you believe it doesn't work? That would be a libcurl bug...

Comment: @DanielStenberg attempting a connection to a server from a CentOS7 box is failing with TLS1.3 (using CURL command line), but works with TLS1.2. Code using libcurl is failing from the same box (works fine on Ubuntu), and the above TLSv1_2 code does not change that.

Comment: @cbrng: presumably, you are using a prehistoric curl version

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a c++ question, but in python newest version (3.10) the min req for OpenSSL changed which yielded interrupts in connections made to "outdated" servers that use a lower version of OpenSSL. Sadly, there is no way that you as a client can easily know the versions used by the server.

What you can do is manually changing the versions or even the ciphers used and see which one works, therefore guessing the version the server is using.

If you are having connection issues, I would simple downgrade the library being used. If you want to actually keep using it and enforce newer TLS and SSL standards you need to be aware that older servers might enforce the downgrading.